# TeamCity restores nuget package - running too long in restoring the packages

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to use the nuget install plugin for TeamCity but after running, it takes too long in restoring and installing all the packages in my solution.

Can someone help in nuget restore packages in TeamCity?

[image]

Comment: I believe there is not enough information in here. What's the next step after restore? Are you using `NuGet restore` or `dotnet restore`? Does it hangs always on the same package? Does it works on your local machine? Are you able to share whole log file?

Comment: Did you get a solution.  I'm testing team city in the cloud and the nuget restore is so slow.. I'm at 8 minutes right now and it isn't even close to completing.

Comment: @lucum yes by getting rid of our console application solutions within the project.

Comment: Arg, that sounds more like a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I was researching and solving the same problem. My solution took up to 20 minute(in bad times) to resolve all NuGet packages. Here is what I had found:

1. TeamCity doesn't use the nuget cache because they reassign the env variable for the directory where they keep resolved packages. The details about this you can find on here https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000160524/comments/360000087900
   And here is the reason why they do it https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4277
2. I'm not sure why but the version NuGet that provided by TeamCity v3.5, v4.6 proceed with restore operation slower than other versions.

What I did:

1. In my case I've added the override of the **env.NUGET_PACKAGES** to the home Agent directory (*%teamcity.agent.home.dir%/nuget-cache*) in my
   TeamCity project. That made restore stable not more than 10 minutes. *Be careful because the work and temp directory might be cleared by TeamCity Agent and your cache will not be stable*.
2. I've added the latest stable version of the NuGet.exe file (v5.8.1 in my case) https://www.nuget.org/downloads. Then I'd chosen the **Custom option** for NuGet Install step in TeamCity (NuGet.exe select box) and set the path to my NuGet.exe file in the solution.

After both of these steps, NuGet restore takes up to 1.5 minutes for my solution and this is ok for me.